# Multiselect Search with PDO

Tags: php, search, pdo

I would like to list the selected options. But there are 3 separate selectbox. "Brand", "Fuel" and "Gear". For example, when I select ford brand, it is listed but if I select fuel and gear with brand, I get a wrong list. How should it be?

**DATABASE MEANING**

*TABLE (araclar = "CARS TABLE") arac_marka = "BRANDS" arac_vites = "GEAR" arac_benzin = "FUEL"*

**AND FORM ACTION (SELF)**

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <select name="arac_marka" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Marka Seçin</option>
         <? $marsor=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM araclar'); 
            $marsor->execute(); 
            while ($marcek=$marsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?> 
         <option value="<?=$marcek['arac_marka'];?>">
            <?=$marcek['arac_marka'];?>
         </option>
         <? } ?>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <select name="arac_benzin" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Yakıt Tipi</option>
         <option value="Benzin">Benzin</option>
         <option value="Dizel">Dizel</option>
         <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
         <option value="LPG">LPG</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <select name="arac_vites" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Vites</option>
         <option value="Benzin">Otomatik</option>
         <option value="Dizel">Manuel</option>
         <option value="Hybrid">Yarı Otomatik</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="dtara" value="Filtrele"> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <a href="araclarimiz" class="btn btn-raised">Tüm Araçlar</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

**AND LISTING**

```
<? if(isset($_GET['dtara'])) { 
    $marka=$_GET['arac_marka']; 
    $benzin=$_GET['arac_benzin']; 
    $vites=$_GET['arac_vites']; 
    $asql=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM araclar 
    WHERE arac_marka='$marka' 
    OR arac_benzin='$benzin' 
    OR arac_vites='$vites'"); 
    $asql->execute(); 
} else { 
    $asql=$db->prepare('select * from araclar'); 
    $asql->execute(); 
} 
while ($acek=$asql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?> 
    //Listing Here 
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Just a side comment: That is not how you use ->prepare to safeguard you from sql injection attacks. Some examples: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Thank you for the warning Randall. Which method do you recommend me to use? Or which one do you prefer?

Comment: Build the query dynamically and use placeholders, not the variables, in the query. If both brand and fuel are selected must the match or are they independent?

Comment: As @chris85 said, use placeholders (either ? or :named is up to you), and then put the actual variables of data into the execute(). Main thing is just to keep variable insertion out of the actual sql query setup in your code.

Comment: Could you give me an example chris85? I am learning new and your information is very valuable to me.

Comment: Of using placeholders? Sure but I suspect your current issue is the usage of `or` which makes your current query return all rows.

Comment: It does not work right now. How to list by choice. I want to learn this.

Comment: I've got such example, https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where